# typeahead twitter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js

I am using twitter typeahead for the first time.

I have my json format like :

```
[{"merchant_name":"Myntra"},{"merchant_name":"Adlabs imagica"},{"merchant_name":"godaam"},{"merchant_name":"Homeshop18"},{"merchant_name":"Hotels.com"}]
```

I am converting this into an array and passing it to typeahead function. But this its not wrking. Please help me to solve this issue

```
  $('#search_bar').keyup(function(e){
        var searched = $('#search_bar').val()
        $.getJSON('<?php echo base_url();?>get_data','title='+searched,function(result){
        var elements = [];
        $.each(result,function(i,val){
               elements.push(val.merchant_name)
        })
        $('#searh_bar').typeahead({
                   source:elements
        })
   })
});
```

Comment: there is one typo error in your code..`$('#searh_bar').typeahead({
                   source:elements
        })` ..it should be `search_bar`

Answer (score 0):

If it's really twitter typeahead you're using, then there are at least 2 things wrong here:

1) You shouldn't have to call `.typeahead()` on your elements after each key up, but rather once during initialization.

2) There is no `source` parameter in typeahead.js

From what you are trying to do, it really seems like you need something else: you want to query your server after each key press (use `remote:` for that), and convert the results (use `filter:` for that).

So something like:

```
$('#search_bar').typeahead({
  remote: {
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>get_data?title=%QUERY',
    filter: function(parsedResponse) {
      var elements = [];
      $.each(parsedResponse, function(i, val) {
        elements.push(val.merchant_name);
      });
      return retval;
    }
  }
});
```